# Why the cursor start to jump and stop with phone movement?

Tags: mouse-cursor

My hp mouse cursor start to jump around when my Samsung phone gets closer to it. When I move my phone away from my laptop, then it starts to work. I found this too odd, if any body knows why? Please Help

Answer (score 0):

To communicate between your devices, Bluetooth sends signals over a 2.4GHz radio frequency. This becomes problematic when other nearby devices are also using that frequency.

Still, in theory at least, interference between Bluetooth technologies should be relatively rare with properly designed devices, because their signals are relatively weak at about one milliwatt. However, cell phones emit much more, about 3 milliwatts.

Most of today’s Bluetooth technology uses what’s called
[spread-spectrum frequency hopping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency-hopping_spread_spectrum).
That is, they rotate between 70 randomly chose frequencies within their range, changing many times a second. This makes it unlikely that two devices will share the same frequency. And when they do, they won’t for very long.

In your case, there might be something wrong with one of your Bluetooth devices,
or it might just not be using frequency hopping.
Try using other devices from a different make, to better analyze the problem.